# How do I repeat the users input in python coding?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to coding. How do I repeat the user's input? This is what I have so far, I am creating a shopping stimulation and repeats back at the end what the user inputted.

```
price = {"Coke": 1.50, "DrPepper": 2.00, "Sprite": 1.00, "Water": 0.50}
shopping_basket = {}

print("Welcome to the online drink store!\nThese are the drinks we offer\n1. Coke: 1.50\n2. DrPepper: 2.00\n3. Sprite 1.00\n4. Water: 0.50")

drink2 = 1
total_cost, total = 0, 0

while drink2 != 0:
    option = int(input("Which drink would you like to purchase?: "))

    if option == 1:
        qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = qnty * 1.50
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 2:
        qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = qnty * 2.00
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 3:
        qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = qnty * 1.00
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 4:
        qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = qnty * 0.50
        print("The price is: " + str(total))

    total_cost += total

    drink2 = int(input("Would you like another item? enter Yes (1) or No (0): "))


print("The total price of your basket is: ", total_cost)
```

Comment: use `while` loop and `break`

Comment: post some code to what you're doing so we can direct you in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

using for loop

```
user_entry = []

for x in range(n): # here n is the number of times you want to reapeat it
    x = input()
    user_entry.append(x)
```